# How can I detect if my application is running in x64debug?

Tags: x64dbg, anti-debugging, c#

I am writing my own applications to practice reversing. I want to be able to detect debuggers and change the execution in response.

When building the application, I am easily able to detect it is being debugged with
`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` or kernel32.dll's `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent`method.

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                //code if being debugged
            }
```

When I debug my release in x64dbg though, the debugger is not detected. Is there a way to detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` detects only managed debuggers, whereas the code you mentioned `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent`, should work on any kind of debugger, provided there is no anti-anti-debugging protection applied.
Managed debuggers, refer to those such as your .net managed debugger.

Note that [CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-checkremotedebuggerpresent), when the handle is set to the current process, is essentially the same as [IsDebuggerPresent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-isdebuggerpresent)

IsDebuggerPresent is the simplest way to check if a debugger is attached to your process, but also the easiest debugging detection technique to bypass.

You can checkout this article for a list of some of the common techniques used (there are many ways to detect !) : https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/367-anti-reverse-engineering-protection-techniques-to-use-before-releasing-software